# Are questions about academic club on toptic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness

I don't know if there are different definitions for academic club, but the club I join is a group of young people, discuss about academic topis such as philosophy (what is freedom?), ecology (wet land in Mekong Rivers), linguistics, religious, etc. The members are diversity, from undergrad students to non-academians, but none of them are grad student (well, some will be, but when they become grad students, they won't have time to be active on the club). The mentors of the club are from PhD to old professors. There is used to have an institute sponsored it, but now it's only the name, not the money anymore.

Will questions about academic clubs be on topic? [On topic questions in this site](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are about:

> - Life as a graduate student, postdoctoral researcher, university professor
> - Transitioning from undergraduate to graduate researcher
> - Inner workings of research departments
> - Requirements and expectations of academicians
> - University-level pedagogy

If it's not, I think this kind of question will be on topic on Community Building SE.

---

The question I'm about to ask is how to gently tell a person in a discuss group that they overtalks and try to take the leader position but fails to make a good, agreed by others argument.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what the point of the question is. You might try suggesting a few proposed questions here, so that you get some feedback before posting them on the main site.

Comment: The question I'm about to ask is how to gently tell a person in a discuss group that they overtalks and try to take the leader position but fails to make a good, agreed by others argument.

Comment: That question would fit much better on Workplace.SE, since it's not really specific to academia.

Comment: [Are questions about academic club on toptic?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/3210/26826) in Workplace if you are interest.